# Setting inline property with vuejs 1.0

Tags: javascript, vue.js

[image]

I'm trying out vuejs by following along with the laracasts series of webcasts on this. In https://laracasts.com/series/learning-vuejs/episodes/5 , Jeffery Way shows the code in the screenshot above.

That worked with vue < 1.0 , but there has been an api rewrite and this no longer works. I have looked at http://vuejs.org/api/ but have not been able to find a way to set a property inline although I know I could do this in the viewmodel.

How can I do this?

Comment: What are you exactly trying to do? just asign `isVisible` property to false? or hide something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I *believe* you're looking for:

```
v-on:click="isVisible = false"
```

or the shorter:

```
@click="isVisible = false"
```

The documentation for it can be found here: http://vuejs.org/api/#v-on

If that's not what you're looking for please clear up your question.